# How to implement calculating table cell width like they actually do in html - manually?

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I am stuck with this issue. I am using spipu/html2pdf for generating pdf files. So I have my total width of the page known. But the pdf I am generating will have dynamic tables (meaning I am not aware of how many column / what the size of each column would be while generating) so I want to implement the standard html like behaviour.

**ie.**
If I put width of the table 100% the table should take 100% of the available space and the table cells should be distributed sensibly. How can I do that?

I have tried flex but spipu/html2pdf does'nt have support for it (and it make sense considering the static nature of pdf).

Can anybody help me with a good way to make this possible?

literally I want to implement how the css `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` is implementd - but manually. because spipu/html2pdf requires you to specify the width in `td` not on `tr` or `table`

**Update**

*A little background* - The thing is I am presenting a rich text box to the user for adding extra details. which result in half of the pdf's contents known, but the other half completly unknown. As for the security, I am only allowing a subset of tags like `h1` - `h6`, `p`, `ul`, `li` and `table` and some of their respective attributes. here is where the issue. The rich text box behave exactly like i want (because its html is rendered in browser).

The only issue is when the user specify the width on the `table` instead of `table-cell` and so I want to implement the table's width calculating mechanism so that the report have the same styling. If the user provides a fixed width to `table-cell`. This is perfectly fine. But if the user provides a 100% width (or any % value) on the `table` the browser renders this correctly. But the html2pdf just calculate the width from the column.

**How I am doing things now:**

There is no heavy processing involved here anywhere just some for compatibility issues. The html is sanitized before storing it in the database.

while generating the report,

I just put the contents like

```php
$data = preg_replace('some unkown tag to html2pdf', 'replaced with compatible tags and proper stying', $users_data);
$html2Pdf->writeHtml($data)
```

If I want the tables data I can do

```php
$data = preg_match('/.*?<table(.*?)>(.*?)<\/table>.*?/', $match)

// so $match have the tables attributes and elments inside
```

What do I do from here?

Comment: I'm sure you can guess the number of columns in PHP. Then, you can divide 100/number_columns and use it as `td` witdh. The problem is that all `td` will have the same width. If the content of the colums is a string, you can guess the length of each row td and make a function that calculates the % width needed for each one.

Comment: For my case the column being equal is somewhat acceptable. But I have no idea how to guess the number of column in table.

Comment: Add some code to your question and I could help you out. To print some data you need that data in the first place. If you have the data, you know it's length. You can do a `count($data['fields'])` or something to know how much items there are.

Comment: That is the problem I don’t have access to the code (like staticaly) The input comes from the user. Wait I ll update a little more details

Comment: It does not matter where it comes from. I figure that you do a `foreach` or something to print the table. Before the `foreach` you can do a `count();` to get the number of td that will be created. Post the part of your code that creates the table.

Comment: There is no for each or any thing I just prints them. I do a little processing before hand. If thats what you are asking I can paste those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225518/discussion-between-hache-raw-and-mohamed-mufeed).